# Adding format characters such as \t and \n to a string of JSON so they will work in a linux echo command

Tags: linux, go

I have an open ssh connection to a linux machine. I am creating a tempfile and need to write formatted Json to it using the echo command. Is there anyway I can easily add the \t and \n where necessary so it ends up being formatted json in the tempfile? Before I resort to creating a function that parses through it and manually adds the \t and \n.

```
jsonData := "{\"data\":[{\"id\": \"1000\", \"name\":\"Product 1\"}, {\"id\": \"2000\", \"name\":\"Product 2\"}, {\"id\": \"3000\", \"name\":\"Product 3\"}]}"

// Create a temp file
session1, err := conn.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to create session: " + err.Error())
}
defer session1.Close()

var tmpFileName bytes.Buffer
session1.Stdout = &tmpFileName
if err := session1.Run("mktemp"); err != nil {
    panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
}

// Write json to temp file
session2, err := conn.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to create session: " + err.Error())
}
defer session2.Close()

if err := session2.Run("echo " + jsonData + ">> " + tmpFileName.String()); err != nil {
    panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json.MarshalIndent`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#MarshalIndent):

```golang
out, err := json.MarshalIndent(json.RawMessage(jsonData), "", "    ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

cmd := exec.Command("echo", string(out))
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/J4Z5txNOmgP

---

Depending on how `session2.Run` is implemented you may need to escape and explicitly quote the formatted json string.

```golang
// this is a naive single quote bash-specific escape, if this isn't
// sufficient for your use case you'll have to improve on it.
jsonData = strings.ReplaceAll(string(out), "'", `'"'"'`)
cmd := fmt.Sprintf("echo '%s' >> %s", jsonData, tmpFileName)
if err := session2.Run(cmd); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response! However, at the end of all of this I am not ending up with a single string that contains \t and \n going into the echo command. The var out is formatted as json with the indents and new lines, but that is not what I should be passing into session2.Run. I believe session2.Run needs a version such as: "{"data":\n\t\t\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t\t and so on... At the end of the day I need to be able to call cat tmpFileName on the actual linux box with the formatted json in the file passed through an echo command.

Comment: If this code was running on the actual linux machine that needed to do this, I believe this would be much easier and I could use some io/os functions. But since I am running this Go code on a different machine and it is responsible for using ssh to connect and create a tempFile with formatted json in it, I believe my options are limited to writing to the file with an echo command only.

Comment: Did you use the `fmt.Sprintf` like in the second half of the answer? If you did, then change `%q` to `%s`, I didn't meant to use `%q`, my bad.

Comment: I apologize I did not try incorporating the second part. Let me see.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I know what I am doing seems a bit crazy but would you agree that since I am not running this Go code on the machine directly and doing this through ssh that this is probably the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way, I'm not sure how reliable the single-quote escaping is. An alternative approach would be to create the file with session1 and then, instead of session2, do something like `exec.Command("scp", "localjsonfile", "remotetempfile")`. But I don't know whether one's better than the other. As long as you know that the cmd string that you're passing to `Run` is correct, using your approach should be as good as anything, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think I can pass the localJsonFile through an ssh command to a remote server which is why I have to do it this way.